# How do I compute this monodromy action on the cohomology of an elliptic curve explicitly?

Tags: complex-analysis, homology-cohomology, elliptic-curves, fundamental-groups

Let $\Delta^*$ be the unit disc minus 0 in the complex plane with parameter $\lambda$ and consider the fibration $X \to \Delta^*$ given by the (projectivization of) the equation $y^2 = x(x-1)(x-\lambda)$.

A generator of the fundamental group of $\Delta^*$ (say a counter clockwise loop around $|\lambda| = 1/2$ induces an action on the (singular) cohomology of the fiber over a point, say at $\lambda = 1/2$.

This cohomology is a free group of rank $2$ and I know for abstract reasons that the action has to be unipotent. How can I compute this explicitly (ie, pick a nice basis for the cohomology and show that the action is the standard unipotent)?

Comment: This is Picard-Lefschetz theory here : there is a vanishing cycle δ and the monodromy is essentially x↦x±⟨x,δ⟩δ (sorry I didn't remember if it + or -, hence the ±, but this can be computed explicitly).

Comment: Thanks, searching for the term gave me some posts that seem to provide geometric intuition (but let me try to work it out for myself first).

Comment: Sure, this is not an easy topic and it certainly takes some time to fully understand it. If you have any question, maybe I can help you. (The case of relative dimension 1 is probably easier than the general case, but I first learned the general case)

Comment: OK, so far I understand why the vanishing cycle is fixed (in cohomology) and why the other cycles are of "generalized eigenvalue 1" because of the monodromy fixing the cup product. What I don't understand yet is why the coefficient has to be exactly the intersection product which I guess is the core of the theorem (and I think this is only true if $x,\delta$ are dual integrally). Do you have a reference where I can read about this? (I don't think working locally helps but I might be wrong!)

Comment: Yes of course the formula (so called Picard-Lefschetz formula) is the core of the theorem. But no, the formula hold for any $x$ (in fact, if $x$ were the dual of $\delta$, then $\langle x,\delta\rangle=1$ so the formula would have another form). The best reference I know is SGA7, but it is in french. It is also done in Freitag-Kiehl but the context is étale cohomology (the place I was working on). This is probably done in many other sources for the complex analytic case but I don't know them.

Comment: But the Picard-Lefschetz is actually a local result. Local on the base, but this is obvious and you are actually already in the local situation with a small disk around the origin), but also local around the singularity of the special fiber, though it require a precision. In fact the action of the monodromy is actually locally zero, but it is local because it factors through the Milnor's fiber. So yes, working locally helps...

Comment: Well, the reason I thought it wouldn't hold for, say $\delta' = \delta/2$ is that $x = x \pm \langle x,\delta\rangle\delta = x \pm 2\langle x,2\delta'\rangle\delta' = x \pm 4\langle x,\delta'\rangle\delta'$. Etale cohomology is just as good for me too!

Comment: I don't get your objection. What is the problem with your $\delta'$ ? The vanishing cycle $\delta$ is uniquely determined up to a sign (which doesn't change the formula), so your $\delta'$ is not the vanishing cycle (it is half a vanishing cycle...)

Comment: Ah I see. I think I misunderstood the terminology of vanishing cycle!

Comment: As for locality, here's my objection to it: Locally (around the singularity), the surface just looks like $k[z,w,\lambda]/(z^2+w^2 - \lambda)$ and generically, this is just $\mathbb P^1$. There is no non trivial 1 dimensional cohomology to speak of or compute the monodromy action on. Thanks for answering my questions so far!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116516/discussion-between-roland-and-asvin).

Comment: I gave more details in the chat.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now!